# How to check onClick on an element in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to check if I click on a `react-select` element. I thought doing it by id and check the mouse event if hits the component that I want. It seems that it doesn't accept `id` as param and it doesn't have one. So I can't check it with event listener.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Adding an id to the react-select or doing it in another way. Keep in mind that I need to know whether I click on the area of the select or outside.

Here is my code:

```
<Select
  defaultValue={defaultValue}
  options={options}
  styles={selectStyle()}
  onFocus={onFocus}
  onChange={onChange}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  value={value}
  id="123" // This way doesn't work
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onClick` attribute.

```
const clickHandler = () => {
console.log("Select is clicked");
}

<Select
  defaultValue={defaultValue}
  options={options}
  styles={selectStyle()}
  onFocus={onFocus}
  onChange={onChange}
  onClick = {clickHandler}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  value={value}
  id="123" // This way doesn't work
/>
```

Comment: It will not work because if I click outside onClick will not be involved

Comment: if you want to handle clicks outside of select then you have to do the same to its parent component